# Tracing slow user login-in sessions in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, session, authentication, database-performance

Background:

We have number of databases of the similar size and identical schema. All of them have identical settings and are placed on the same instance. Everyone uses an application to access and query databases. Within the application all connection strings are identical (except login and password) for all databases. Many users experience significant slowness when logging into and querying one of our databases, but not the other ones.

Problem:

One of the databases gradually became slower and slower to access. Query execution time is also affected, but not as significantly as the time it takes for the user to log in. Now it takes around 50 seconds to login. For all other databases log-in time is only about 4-5 seconds.

Question:

I would like to compare normal log-in sessions on "healthy databases" to the log-in session on the problematic database. Could you please suggest a way to monitor what exactly happens within the log-in session? I know how to trace queries run against specific database, but I don't know what to look for to find what makes logging in slow. Would either profiler or extended events show such information? Is there any other way to analyse what happens during the time user waits to log in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SQL Server Profiler to trace every query sent to the ddbb, and with the ability to filter based on user name, database name, etc.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/ms175047.aspx

I would take a look at ddbb indexes and statistics, as these are the areas that could slow your ddbb if are not well maintained.

Comment: Thank you Oscar. Will it show the execution time for each query run through the application?

Comment: @QWE Yes, both, start time and end time

Comment: Can I recommend @Oscar identifying some of the _events_ and _columns_ by name in your answer that would be useful to trace? For example, `SQL:BatchCompleted` and `SQL:StmtCompleted` events with the `Duration`, `StartTime` and `EndTime` columns checked.